# Custom Class Attribute in Org Mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have a basic ordered list in `org` mode. After exporting to HTML it takes the default class that org mode assigned:

`<ol class="org-ol">`

For some lists, however, I'm trying to assign a custom class (like "special_list", for example).

`<ol class="special_list">`

The org mode documentation says you could add an attribute in this fashion:

`#+ATTR_HTML: :class special_list
1. First point
2. Second point`

But that doesn't seem to work in this case. Do I have the syntax wrong, or is there a different method for applying custom classes?

Answer (score 9):

The `:class` attribute does not seem to apply to lists.

However, you can wrap your list in a custom div this way:

```
#+begin_pepe
1. One
2. Two
#+end_pepe
```

This will produce the following HTML:

```
<div class="pepe">
 <ol class="org-ol">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
 </ol>
</div>
```

So you can use a CSS selector for that list such as `div.pepe ol`.